# How To Add CSS Class to SimpleMarkerSymbol in GraphicsLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please let me know if there is a way to bind a CSS class `.marker` to an ArcGIS `SimpleMarkerSymbol` in a graphic layer?

I have a `SimpleMarkerSymbol` called `schoolMarker` which I am styling it using ESRI's options but I need to add more CSS styles like `.marker`

```
var schoolMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    schoolMarker.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE);
    schoolMarker.setSize(30);
    schoolMarker.setOutline(null);
    schoolMarker.setColor(new Color([255,116,0,0.25]));
```

Here is the CSS class:

```
.marker{
   stroke-linecap: round;
   stroke-linejoin: round;
   stroke-opacity: 1.0;
   fill-opacity: 1.0;
   background-color: rgb(0, 89, 190);
   stroke: rgb(0, 89, 190);
   fill: rgb(0, 89, 190);
   fill-opacity: 1;
   stroke-width: 70pt;
   stroke-opacity: 1;
   opacity: 0.12;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/styling_svg_enrollment.html) uses the layer's `feature-draw` event to get access to the marker's/feature's underlying SVG node, you can add a custom CSS class that way:

```
// require "dojo/on" as "on"
on(graphicsLayer, "graphic-draw", function (evt) {
  evt.node.setAttribute("class", "marker");
});
```

Or, if your layer has an id set (e.g. `new GraphicsLayer({ id: "circles" });`) you can use that in your CSS definition by appending `_layer` to its name:

```
#circles_layer circle { /* CSS here */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment chrki, but the first example is using FeatureLayer how can I use same mechanism in GraphicsLayer?

Comment: @user1106951 I tested both solutions with GraphicsLayer and it worked, see demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/TityFSESgxE7l6ZvJVJm?p=preview

Comment: @user1106951 Figured it out I think: 1. Move the `on` block outside of the `$.each` (move it above or below), it only needs to run once, 2. event name is `graphic-draw` (you added an `s`), 3. looks like you need to set a default marker symbol, i.e. include the `schoolMarker` code from your original post and set the symbol on the graphics: `var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, schoolMarker);`

Comment: Thanks a lot chrki, Can I also ask you to take a look at thois post as well? apparently no body has idea about it! http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220851/how-to-create-heat-map-based-on-graphicslayer-instead-of-featurelayer-in-arcgis

Comment: @user1106951 I might take a look later. Give it some time though, that question was only asked yesterday and it's the weekend, I'm sure someone here knows an answer :)

Comment: I really really appreciate if you kindly take a look at it when you had time. Once again Tahnks